# rsync permissioning?

Tags: linux, permissions, rsync

I have run the command

```
sudo rsync --chmod=a+rwx testfile testfile2
```

This creates a file `testfile2` but the permissions on it are `755 (-rwxr-xr-x)`

Can someone explain how to make it so the permissions are `777 (-rwxrwxrwx)`?

Answer (score 15):

Use

```
sudo rsync --perms --chmod=777 testfile testfile2
```

or

```
sudo rsync --perms --chmod=a+rwx testfile testfile2
```

Comment: yup, from man page: The resulting value is treated as though it were the permissions that the sending side supplied for the file,  which  means  that this  option  can  seem  to  have no effect on existing files if --perms is not enabled.

Comment: @Nerdling - Exactly...

Comment: I get `Invalid argument passed to --chmod (777)` with the first option. Seems to be explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1571111/533832)?

Answer (score 6):

Using --chmod=777 with rsync may fail:

```
sudo rsync --perms --chmod=777 ./testfile ./testfile2
rsync: Invalid argument passed to --chmod (777) 
rsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1) at main.c(1453) [client=3.0.9]
```

However, these are successful:

```
sudo rsync --perms --chmod=u+rwx ./testfile ./testfile2
sudo rsync --perms --chmod=g+rwx ./testfile ./testfile2
sudo rsync --perms --chmod=o+rwx ./testfile ./testfile2
```

i.e. add (+) permissions for user (u), group (g) or other (o) respectively.

Also (a)=all is successful:

```
sudo rsync --perms --chmod=a+rwx ./testfile ./testfile2
```

or alternatively:

```
sudo rsync --perms --chmod=ugo+rwx ./testfile ./testfile2
```

That --perms can replaced by -p with same results.

Revoking (-) permissions works the same way and even comma separated combinations of adding and revoking:

```
sudo rsync --perms --chmod=u-rwx,o+rwx ./testfile ./testfile2
```

Comment: `chmod 777`: nonononono! Never ever run `chmod 777`. It is practically never required! Not even for "testing purposes". If the file is readable, then it's readable. If it's writable by the `user` or `group` that need to write to it, then it's writable. There is absolutely zero need to give everyone write permissions, and forgetting to `chmod` it back to something sane is exactly how multinationals get hacked. Just don't do it. Ever. I wrote [an introduction of Unix permissions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35895436/660921). Please read it!

Comment: `o+rwx` is the same effect/problems (gives "other" read/write access, which is everyone!)

Comment: The header reads "rsync permissioning", i.e. the question is about correct syntax of rsync.

Answer (score 2):

I would be lying if I said “i found this in the documentation”, only in an [SO question](https://serverfault.com/q/796330/88431), but still it works!

```
--perms  --chmod=D770,F660
```

gets you 'executable' on *directories* (alias: *directories are browsable*) while all *files* are non-executable. (=just what the doctor ordered. Same thing [can be achieved](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/416877/what-is-a-capital-x-in-posix-chmod) with the regular chmod command by using an uppercase X `-x+rwX`, but not with rsync...) so this is just nice to know.